# Skip an OSX version with App Store upgrades?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I have a MacBook running Snow Leopard and newer MacBook Air running Lion.  If I buy the Mountain Lion upgrade through the App Store on my Air, will I be able to use the same App Store purchase on my older MacBook?

Or are OS upgrades not multi-machine friendly (somehow different from other apps that are pay-once download-many)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade to Mountain Lion from both Lion and Snow Leopard (SL). With SL you will need to be running the latest version 10.6.8 and then you can just buy it through the app store.

check this link for more details:
[Apple OSX Upgrade](http://www.apple.com/osx/how-to-upgrade/)

You just need to make sure your machine can handle Mountain Lion which you can see with this app from the app store [Mac Tracker - its a free app.](https://itunes.apple.com/nz/app/mactracker/id430255202?mt=12)

OS' are like normal apps - they can be installed on up to 5 machines.

Good Luck on the upgrade:-)

Answer (score 1):

The Licence Agreement for Mountain Lion may be different in your jurisdiction however the UK Mac App Store states for the OS X Mountain Lion License Agreement:

> B. Mac App Store License.  If you obtained a license for the Apple
>   Software from the Mac App Store, then subject to the terms and
>   conditions... you are granted a limited non-transferable, no exclusive
>   license:
>
> (i) to download, install, use and run for personal, non-commercial
>   use, one copy of the the Apple software on each Apple-branded computer
>   running OS X Lion or OS X Snow Leopard ... that you own or control.

If you are a commercial entity, then different rules apply

Both machines need the Mac App store to be accessed using the same AppleID used to purchase Mountain Lion.  You can also save yourself the 4GB download a second time around, by copying the Mountain lion Installer from the /Applications directory tot he other machine once downloaded in full, note the installer is deleted once it is installed so cancel the install once it is downloaded, copy it somewhere safe, then upgrade away.